# Using a keyword as an identifier in an SDK

Tags: c++, sdk, console-application

I want to use a SDK built for a scanner, but (the .hpp file) it contains an enumeration which uses the 'default' keyword as an identifier.

```
struct laser_extraction {
    enum type {
        default = FUSION_LASER_EXTRACTION_DEFAULT,  // It's a keyword

        strict = FUSION_LASER_EXTRACTION_STRICT,

        with_noise_elimination = FUSION_LASER_EXTRACTION_WITH_NOISE_ELIMINATION,

        unfiltered = FUSION_LASER_EXTRACTION_UNFILTERED,
    };
};
```

Is there a workaround or something for this? I don't even use this struct in the main program (the .cpp file), but the build is not successfull.

Comment: Looks like the SDK is a `C` library.  You will need to wrap the above in a `C` library of your own and only expose valid C++ from your library.

Comment: Hang on `default` is also a `C` keyword https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword .  Can you edit the header file and change `default` to something else ?

Comment: `default = FUSION_LASER_EXTRACTION_DEFAULT,  // It's a keyword` -- Who wrote this, and how was this ever supposed to compile successfully to begin with?  That is the real mystery. -- *Is there a workaround or something for this?* -- Contact the author, and yell at them for doing this.

Comment: You can try to `#define default` before including the header and `#undef default` right after: `#define default laser_extraction_default` `#include "sdk.h"` `#undef default`. if it is not used as a keyword there it should be ok.